# Detecting an undefined object property

Tags: javascript, object, undefined, object-property

How do I check if an object property in JavaScript is undefined?

Comment: Look for recent answers in this thread. In 'modern' javascript, consider using the `in` operator:`'key' in obj ? 'obj has key property' : 'obj does not have key property'` `

Comment: I’m open to picking a new ‘correct’ answer if you have one in mind that covers the old way as completely as the current one and also addresses more modern options.

Answer (score 2940, accepted):

The usual way to check if the value of a property is the special value `undefined`, is:

```js
if(o.myProperty === undefined) {
  alert("myProperty value is the special value `undefined`");
}
```

To check if an object does not actually have such a property, and will therefore return `undefined` by default when you try to access it:

```js
if(!o.hasOwnProperty('myProperty')) {
  alert("myProperty does not exist");
}
```

To check if the value associated with an identifier is the special value `undefined`, *or* if that identifier has not been declared:

```js
if(typeof myVariable === 'undefined') {
  alert('myVariable is either the special value `undefined`, or it has not been declared');
}
```

Note: this last method is the only way to refer to an **undeclared** identifier without an early error, which is different from having a value of `undefined`.

In versions of JavaScript prior to ECMAScript 5, the property named "undefined" on the global object was writeable, and therefore a simple check `foo === undefined` might behave unexpectedly if it had accidentally been redefined. In modern JavaScript, the property is read-only.

However, in modern JavaScript, "undefined" is not a keyword, and so variables inside functions can be named "undefined" and shadow the global property.

If you are worried about this (unlikely) edge case, you can use [the void operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) to get at the special `undefined` value itself:

```js
if(myVariable === void 0) {
  alert("myVariable is the special value `undefined`");
}
```

Comment: if something is null the it is defined (as null), but you can conjugate the too checks. The annoying detail of the above code is that you can't define a function to check it, well you can define the function... but try to use it.

Comment: @neu-rah why can't you write a function? why wouldn't something like this work? It seems to work for me. Is there a case I'm not considering? http://jsfiddle.net/djH9N/6/

Comment: @Zack Your tests for isNullorUndefined did not consider the case where you call isNullOrUndefined(f) and f is undeclared (i.e. where there is no "var f" declaration).

Comment: Blah, thousands of votes now. This is the worst possible way to do it. I hope passers-by see this comment and decide to check… ahem… *other* answers.

Comment: You can just use `obj !== undefined` now. `undefined` used to be mutable, like `undefined = 1234` what would cause interesting results. But after Ecmascript 5, it's not writable anymore, so we can use the simpler version. http://www.codereadability.com/how-to-check-for-undefined-in-javascript/

Comment: @Ryan what "other answer"?

Comment: @user1032531: I’d recommend mine

Comment: grrr im just gonna `typeof window !== typeof undefined`... no chance of misspelling undefined and works on the global scope

Comment: eslint advices against using `hasOwnProperty`. Use the `in` operator, see recent answers as examples.

Answer (score 985):

I believe there are a number of incorrect answers to this topic. Contrary to common belief, "undefined" is **not** a keyword in JavaScript and can in fact have a value assigned to it.

## Correct Code

The most robust way to perform this test is:

```
if (typeof myVar === "undefined")
```

This will always return the correct result, and even handles the situation where `myVar` is not declared.

## Degenerate code. DO NOT USE.

```
var undefined = false;  // Shockingly, this is completely legal!
if (myVar === undefined) {
    alert("You have been misled. Run away!");
}
```

Additionally, `myVar === undefined` will raise an error in the situation where myVar is undeclared.

Comment: I agree that undefined is not a keyword, undefined is a predefined variable with an undefined value. Something like alert, this is a function that you can override with something else. Alert is also not a keyword but a part of the standard function set, ap part of the window object that has a global scope. Like undefined you can also override the alert function by re-assigning it. For example: window.alert = function(s) { console.log(s); } is also a legal construction.

Comment: What about `if(typeof myVar != "undefined")`. Is the `"!="` acceptable?

Comment: in addition to Marks comments, I don't get this: "myVar === undefined will raise an error in the situation where myVar is undeclared." - why is this bad? Why would I *not* want to have an error if I'm referencing undeclared variables?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, it would be, because `typeof` will always return a string, making the type-safe comparison unnecessary. It's just considered a good practice to use `===` resp. `!==` exclusively. Actually I think that jQuery uses only `!=`.

Comment: Also keep in mind you can always do `void 0` to get the value that `undefined` points to. So you can do `if (myVar === void 0)`. the `0` isn't special, you can literally put any expression there.

Comment: In modern browsers (FF4+, IE9+, Chrome unknown), it's no longer possible to modify `undefined`. [MDN: undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Comment: [fiddle for demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/rblakeley/rvk4kweg/) of this point

Comment: @Stijn: While it's not possible to modify the global `undefined`, it's still possible to *redefine* it locally as is shown in this answer. Copy and paste the answer's sample code into a modern browser and you'll see that `myVar === undefined` can still cause problems.

Comment: @KevinMeredith "Is the "!=" acceptable?" It certainly is. In my book it is *better* than `!==` as it's shorter and the longer forms offers no benefits i.c.w. `typeof`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as well. The question was about undefined object properties, not undefined variables. There is a significant difference. It is, for example, perfectly reasonable to do `if (obj.field === undefined)`.

I think the risk of someone doing `var undefined = false;` is overrated. You will have to program unreasonably defensive if you want to protect against all such kinds of side effects caused by poor programming.

Comment: Rule X: NEVER use reserved words as variablename, functionname or whatever. Don't understand you get so many positive votes. Because it is possible it doesn't mean it's legal, besides, it can change in future and your code (and everything rely on it) doesn't work any longer. This is a bad/unreliable example and shows you how not do it.

Comment: since writable property of undefined is set to false. even if you assign false to undefined it will not get set. so undefined will be "undefined" always not false so your answer makes no sense. You can check that in ECMA script specification for JavaScript.

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3

Comment: Just from experience, I think you *really* want your code to throw that ReferenceError if a variable is not declared. It's so frustrating when things silently fail.

Comment: @MarkPflug: It didn’t make sense in 2010 either, sorry. `undefined` is not a keyword in 2017. You can still use `var undefined = false;`. The answer to this has always been “don’t do that” rather than “use convoluted workarounds for something that is never the case”.

Comment: Funny that people suggest these silly and error-prone hacks to avoid a shadowed `undefined` (which could only be done by a terrible developer), yet they blithely use other global identifiers that could also have been shadowed. Bizarre. Just bizarre.

Comment: ^ totally agree. someone who might shadow `undefined` might also shadow `Math` or assign `Function.prototype.apply` or _anything_ else that you take for granted! Please. ^ totally agree. someone who might shadow `undefined` might also shadow `Math` or assign `Function.prototype.apply` or _anything_ else that you take for granted! Please. How about `Object.prototype.toJSON=()=>({rick:'rolled'})`? `JSON.stringify({hello:'world'}) === '{"rick":"rolled"}'` then. There are so many ways to break the expected JavaScript environment, you can't write code that works around all of those things.

Comment: But it is [no longer relevant with ECMAScript 5 (and later)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-can-i-check-for-undefined-in-javascript/3390468#3390468)?

Comment: do you need to check on window object if typeof myVar === "undefined" or is it obsolete if you use if(myvar) {}

Answer (score 287):

Many answers here are vehement in recommending `typeof`, but `typeof` *is a bad choice*. It should *never* be used for checking whether variables have the value `undefined`, because it acts as a combined check for the value `undefined` and for whether a variable exists. In the vast majority of cases, you know when a variable exists, and `typeof` will just introduce the potential for a silent failure if you make a typo in the variable name or in the string literal `'undefined'`.

```
var snapshot = …;

if (typeof snaposhot === 'undefined') {
    //         ^
    // misspelled¹ – this will never run, but it won’t throw an error!
}
```

```
var foo = …;

if (typeof foo === 'undefned') {
    //                   ^
    // misspelled – this will never run, but it won’t throw an error!
}
```

So unless you’re doing feature detection², where there’s uncertainty whether a given name will be in scope (like checking `typeof module !== 'undefined'` as a step in code specific to a CommonJS environment), `typeof` is a harmful choice when used on a variable, and the correct option is to compare the value directly:

```
var foo = …;

if (foo === undefined) {
    ⋮
}
```

Some common misconceptions about this include:

- that reading an “uninitialized” variable (`var foo`) or parameter (`function bar(foo) { … }`, called as `bar()`) will fail. This is simply not true – variables without explicit initialization and parameters that weren’t given values always become `undefined`, and are always in scope.
- that `undefined` can be overwritten. It’s true that `undefined` isn’t a keyword, but it *is* read-only and non-configurable. There are other built-ins you probably don’t avoid despite their non-keyword status (`Object`, `Math`, `NaN`…) and practical code usually isn’t written in an actively malicious environment, so this isn’t a good reason to be worried about `undefined`. (But if you are writing a code generator, feel free to use `void 0`.)

With how variables work out of the way, it’s time to address the actual question: object properties. There is no reason to ever use `typeof` for object properties. The earlier exception regarding feature detection doesn’t apply here – `typeof` only has special behaviour on variables, and expressions that reference object properties are not variables.

This:

```
if (typeof foo.bar === 'undefined') {
    ⋮
}
```

is *always exactly equivalent* to this³:

```
if (foo.bar === undefined) {
    ⋮
}
```

and taking into account the advice above, to avoid confusing readers as to why you’re using `typeof`, because it makes the most sense to use `===` to check for equality, because it could be refactored to checking a variable’s value later, and because it just plain looks better, **you should always use `=== undefined`³ here as well**.

Something else to consider when it comes to object properties is whether you really want to check for `undefined` at all. A given property name can be absent on an object (producing the value `undefined` when read), present on the object itself with the value `undefined`, present on the object’s prototype with the value `undefined`, or present on either of those with a non-`undefined` value. `'key' in obj` will tell you whether a key is anywhere on an object’s prototype chain, and `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, 'key')` will tell you whether it’s directly on the object. I won’t go into detail in this answer about prototypes and using objects as string-keyed maps, though, because it’s mostly intended to counter all the bad advice in other answers irrespective of the possible interpretations of the original question. Read up on [object prototypes on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) for more!

<sub>¹ unusual choice of example variable name? this is real dead code from the NoScript extension for Firefox.</sub>
<sub>² don’t assume that not knowing what’s in scope is okay in general, though. bonus vulnerability caused by abuse of dynamic scope: [Project Zero 1225](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/project-zero/issues/detail?id=1225&desc=6)</sub>
<sub>³ once again assuming an ES5+ environment and that `undefined` refers to the `undefined` property of the global object.</sub>

Comment: Any non-default context can also overwrite, say, `Math`, or `Object`, or `setTimeout`, or literally anything that you expect to find in the global scope by default.

Comment: ohw kay foo !== void 0 works and is shorter guess i can use that :3 and i knew you were referring to yer own answer when ya commented that >:D

Comment: now it doesn't document what it does tho and might be confusing to read so instead i'll make a function isDefined return true if is not void 0 and false if it is and return that instead >:3

Comment: @Fuseteam: Use `!== undefined`. Actually, I should probably remove the advice about `void 0`.

Comment: @Fuseteam: It’s not as readable and has no practical advantages over `undefined`.

Comment: i worked around the readability by wrapping it in a function isDefined(variable) so now i can just call that function to do it like `if(isDefined(variable))//do something` xD
so it's both shorter and reusable i guess

Comment: @Fuseteam: Again, I would strongly recommend not doing that, and writing `if (variable !== undefined)` instead. Comparisons with `undefined` are unambiguous and familiar, redundant wrapper functions create uncertainty (“maybe this also checks for `null`?”) with no readability benefit.

Comment: i was actually looking into what other type of "undefined" values are possible but fair enough

Answer (score 175):

In JavaScript there is **null** and there is **undefined**.  They have different meanings.

- **undefined** means that the variable value has not been defined; it is not known what the value is.
- **null** means that the variable value is defined and set to null (has no value).

Marijn Haverbeke states, in his free, online book "[Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)" (emphasis mine):

> There is also a similar value, null, whose meaning is 'this value is defined, but it does not have a value'. The difference in meaning between undefined and null is mostly academic, and usually not very interesting. **In practical programs, it is often necessary to check whether something 'has a value'. In these cases, the expression something == undefined may be used, because, even though they are not exactly the same value, null == undefined will produce true.**

So, I guess the best way to check if something was undefined would be:

```
if (something == undefined)
```

Object properties should work the same way.

```
var person = {
    name: "John",
    age: 28,
    sex: "male"
};

alert(person.name); // "John"
alert(person.fakeVariable); // undefined
```

Comment: if (something == undefined)

is better written as

  if (something === undefined)

Comment: It should be pointed out that this is not entirely safe. `undefined` is just a variable that can be re-assigned by the user: writing `undefined = 'a';` will cause your code to no longer do what you think it does. Using `typeof` is better and also works for variables (not just properties) that haven't been declared.

Comment: if something is an undefined global variable, (something == undefined) brings up javascript error.

Comment: The problem with this is that if var a = null then a == undefined evaluates to true, even though a is most certainly defined.

Comment: `if (something === undefined)` is not working for me with ie7 or ie8 `if (typeof something  == "undefined")` is.

Comment: This interpretation of the "Eloquent Javascript" comment is _backward_. If you really do just want to check for undefined, the suggested code will not work (it will also detect the condition defined but no value has been assined yet [i.e.null]).a null value. The suggested code "if (something == undefined) ..." checks for _both_ undefined and null (no value set), i.e. it's interpreted as "if ((something is undefined) OR (something is null)) ..." What the author is saying is that often what you _really_ want is to check for _both_ undefined and null.

Answer (score 137):

What does this mean: **"undefined object property"**?

Actually it can mean two quite different things! First, it can mean *the property that has never been defined* in the object and, second, it can mean the *property that has an undefined value*. Let's look at this code:

```
var o = { a: undefined }
```

Is `o.a` undefined? Yes! Its value is undefined. Is `o.b` undefined? Sure! There is no property 'b' at all! OK, see now how different approaches behave in both situations:

```
typeof o.a == 'undefined' // true
typeof o.b == 'undefined' // true
o.a === undefined // true
o.b === undefined // true
'a' in o // true
'b' in o // false
```

We can clearly see that `typeof obj.prop == 'undefined'` and `obj.prop === undefined` are equivalent, and they do not distinguish those different situations. And `'prop' in obj` can detect the situation when a property hasn't been defined at all and doesn't pay attention to the property value which may be undefined.

### So what to do?

1) You want to know if a property is undefined by either the first or second meaning (the most typical situation).

```
obj.prop === undefined // IMHO, see "final fight" below
```

2) You want to just know if object has some property and don't care about its value.

```
'prop' in obj
```

### Notes:

- You can't check an object and its property at the same time. For example, this `x.a === undefined` or this `typeof x.a == 'undefined'` raises `ReferenceError: x is not defined` if x is not defined.
- Variable `undefined` is a global variable (so actually it is `window.undefined` in browsers). It has been supported since ECMAScript 1st Edition and since ECMAScript 5 it is **read only**. So in modern browsers it can't be *redefined to true* as many authors love to frighten us with, but this is still a true for older browsers.

### Final fight: `obj.prop === undefined` vs `typeof obj.prop == 'undefined'`

Pluses of `obj.prop === undefined`:

- It's a bit shorter and looks a bit prettier
- The JavaScript engine will give you an error if you have misspelled `undefined`

Minuses of `obj.prop === undefined`:

- `undefined` can be overridden in old browsers

Pluses of `typeof obj.prop == 'undefined'`:

- It is really universal! It works in new and old browsers.

Minuses of `typeof obj.prop == 'undefined'`:

- `'undefned'` (*misspelled*) here is just a string constant, so the JavaScript engine can't help you if you have misspelled it like I just did.

### Update (for server-side JavaScript):

Node.js supports the global variable `undefined` as `global.undefined` (it can also be used without the 'global' prefix). I don't know about other implementations of server-side JavaScript.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for your comment. I have corrected my answer. In my defense I can say that currently (as of v.0.10.18) [official Node.js documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html) says nothing about `undefined` as a member of `global`. Also neither `console.log(global);` nor `for (var key in global) { ... }` doesn't show *undefined* as a member of *global*. But test like `'undefined' in global` show the opposite.

Comment: It didn't need extra documentation since [it's in the EcmaScript spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.1.3), which also says that `[[Enumerable]]` is false :-)

Comment: Regarding `Minuses of typeof obj.prop == 'undefined'`, this can be avoided by writing as `typeof obj.prop == typeof undefined`. This also gives a very nice symmetry.

Comment: @hlovdal: That’s totally pointless vs. `obj.prop === undefined`.

Comment: When we are true to the question headline **„_Detecting_ an undefined property“**, not true to the (different and much easier) question in the first sentence („check if undefined...“), you answer `if ('foo' in o`)… your answer is truly the first correct answer here. Pretty much everybody else just answers that sentence.

Answer (score 75):

The issue boils down to three cases:

1. The object has the property and its value is not `undefined`.
2. The object has the property and its value is `undefined`.
3. The object does not have the property.

This tells us something I consider important:

**There is a difference between an undefined member and a defined member with an undefined value.**

But unhappily `typeof obj.foo` does not tell us which of the three cases we have. However we can combine this with `"foo" in obj` to distinguish the cases.

```
                               |  typeof obj.x === 'undefined' | !("x" in obj)
1.                     { x:1 } |  false                        | false
2.    { x : (function(){})() } |  true                         | false
3.                          {} |  true                         | true
```

Its worth noting that these tests are the same for `null` entries too

```
                               |  typeof obj.x === 'undefined' | !("x" in obj)
                    { x:null } |  false                        | false
```

I'd argue that in some cases it makes more sense (and is clearer) to check whether the property is there, than checking whether it is undefined, and the only case where this check will be different is case 2, the rare case of an actual entry in the object with an undefined value.

For example: I've just been refactoring a bunch of code that had a bunch of checks whether an object had a given property.

```
if( typeof blob.x != 'undefined' ) {  fn(blob.x); }
```

Which was clearer when written without a check for undefined.

```
if( "x" in blob ) { fn(blob.x); }
```

But as has been mentioned these are not exactly the same (but are more than good enough for my needs).

Comment: Hi Michael.  Great suggestion, and I think it does make things cleaner.  One gotcha that I found, however, is when using the ! operator with "in".  You have to say `if (!("x" in blob)) {}` with brackets around the in, because the ! operator has precedence over 'in'.  Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Sorry Michael, but this is incorrect, or at least misleading, in light of the original question. 'in' is not a sufficient way to test whether an object property has typeof undefined. For proof, please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CsLKJ/4/

Comment: Those two code parts do a different thing! Consider and object given by `a = {b: undefined}`; then `typeof a.b === typeof a.c === 'undefined'` but `'b' in a` and `!('c' in a)`.

Comment: +1. The OP doesn't make it clear whether the property exists and has the value *undefined*, or whether the property itself is undefined (i.e. doesn't exist).

Comment: I would suggest changing point (2.) in your first table to `{ x : undefined }` or at least add it as another alternative to (2.) in the table - I had to think for a moment to realize that point (2.) evaluates to `undefined` (although you mention that later on).

Comment: @mucaho That would be better, but I think there is (or at least used to be?) some issues with a construct like that - that is `undefined` is not  (was not?) guaranteed to be undefined.

Answer (score 48):

```
if ( typeof( something ) == "undefined")
```

This worked for me while the others didn't.

Comment: parens are unnecessary since typeof is an operator

Comment: But they make it clearer what is being checked. Otherwise it might be read as `typeof (something == "undefined")`.

Comment: If you need the parentheses, then you should learn operator precedence in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Comment: Parenthesis are useful precisely because you do NOT need to learn operator precedence in JS, nor do you need to speculate whether future maintenance programmers will need to learn operator precedence in JS.

Comment: Parenthesis are useful to clarify things. But in this case they just make the operator look like a function. No doubt this clarifies the intent of the programmer. But if you're unsure about operator precedence you should rather write it as `(typeof something) === "undefined"`.

Comment: @Robert I agree with your  use of parens (surrounding `typeof`), but in ES6 you may not use parens to call a function, e.g. [`quux \`foo\n${ 42 }bar\``](http://es6-features.org/#RawStringAccess).

Answer (score 44):

I'm not sure where the origin of using `===` with `typeof` came from, and as a convention I see it used in many libraries, but the typeof operator returns a string literal, and we know that up front, so why would you also want to type check it too?

```
typeof x;                      // some string literal "string", "object", "undefined"
if (typeof x === "string") {   // === is redundant because we already know typeof returns a string literal
if (typeof x == "string") {    // sufficient
```

Comment: Great point Eric.  Is there a performance hit from checking type also?

Comment: @Simon: quite the contrary - one could expect slight performance hit from avoiding coercion in '===' case. Quick and dirty test has shown '===' is 5% faster than '==' under FF5.0.1

Comment: More thorough test has shown that under FF,IE and Chrome '==' is more or less faster than '===' (5-10%) and Opera doesn't make any difference at all: http://jsperf.com/triple-equals-vs-twice-equals/6

Comment: Using `==` still requires _at least_ a type check - the interpreter can't compare the two operands without knowing their type first.

Comment: `==` is one less character than `===` :)

Comment: @svidgen You add a smiley, but seeing that the network is the *slowest* chain in the link, I actually believe that you'll see more of a performance gain from leaving out the extra character then you'll ever see from the type checks. 5% of nothing is still nothing. Personally I hate dogmatic coding. I allows you to turn off your brain while typing, but there is *no* reason triple equals would be any safer in this case.

Answer (score 32):

I didn't see (hope I didn't miss it) anyone checking the object before the property. So, this is the shortest and most effective (though not necessarily the most clear):

```
if (obj && obj.prop) {
  // Do something;
}
```

If the obj or obj.prop is undefined, null, or "falsy", the if statement will not execute the code block. This is *usually* the desired behavior in most code block statements (in JavaScript).

### UPDATE: (7/2/2021)

The latest version of JavaScript introduces a new operator for
optional chaining: `?.`

This is probably going to be the most explicit and efficient method of checking for the existence of object properties, moving forward.

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: If you want to know why this works: [Javascript: Logical Operators and truthy / falsy](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/07/advanced-javascript-operators-and-truthy-falsy/)

Comment: if you want to assign the property to a variable if it's defined, not null and not falsey, else use some default value, you can use:  `var x = obj && obj.prop || 'default';`

Comment: I believe the question is for checking against undefined explicitly. Your condition check against all false values of JS.

Comment: Don't do this, it fails if `obj.prop` is `false`, `0`, `""` and various other falsey values.
This is exactly what we should not do and also applies to optional chaining, which should not be used in this manner.

Answer (score 27):

Crossposting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-can-i-check-for-undefined-in-javascript/14305002#14305002) from related question *[How can I check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-can-i-check-for-undefined-in-javascript)*.

*Specific to this question, see test cases with `someObject.<whatever>`.*

---

Some scenarios illustrating the results of the various answers:
http://jsfiddle.net/drzaus/UVjM4/

*(Note that the use of `var` for `in` tests make a difference when in a scoped wrapper)*

Code for reference:

```
(function(undefined) {
    var definedButNotInitialized;
    definedAndInitialized = 3;
    someObject = {
        firstProp: "1"
        , secondProp: false
        // , undefinedProp not defined
    }
    // var notDefined;

    var tests = [
        'definedButNotInitialized in window',
        'definedAndInitialized in window',
        'someObject.firstProp in window',
        'someObject.secondProp in window',
        'someObject.undefinedProp in window',
        'notDefined in window',

        '"definedButNotInitialized" in window',
        '"definedAndInitialized" in window',
        '"someObject.firstProp" in window',
        '"someObject.secondProp" in window',
        '"someObject.undefinedProp" in window',
        '"notDefined" in window',

        'typeof definedButNotInitialized == "undefined"',
        'typeof definedButNotInitialized === typeof undefined',
        'definedButNotInitialized === undefined',
        '! definedButNotInitialized',
        '!! definedButNotInitialized',

        'typeof definedAndInitialized == "undefined"',
        'typeof definedAndInitialized === typeof undefined',
        'definedAndInitialized === undefined',
        '! definedAndInitialized',
        '!! definedAndInitialized',

        'typeof someObject.firstProp == "undefined"',
        'typeof someObject.firstProp === typeof undefined',
        'someObject.firstProp === undefined',
        '! someObject.firstProp',
        '!! someObject.firstProp',

        'typeof someObject.secondProp == "undefined"',
        'typeof someObject.secondProp === typeof undefined',
        'someObject.secondProp === undefined',
        '! someObject.secondProp',
        '!! someObject.secondProp',

        'typeof someObject.undefinedProp == "undefined"',
        'typeof someObject.undefinedProp === typeof undefined',
        'someObject.undefinedProp === undefined',
        '! someObject.undefinedProp',
        '!! someObject.undefinedProp',

        'typeof notDefined == "undefined"',
        'typeof notDefined === typeof undefined',
        'notDefined === undefined',
        '! notDefined',
        '!! notDefined'
    ];

    var output = document.getElementById('results');
    var result = '';
    for(var t in tests) {
        if( !tests.hasOwnProperty(t) ) continue; // bleh

        try {
            result = eval(tests[t]);
        } catch(ex) {
            result = 'Exception--' + ex;
        }
        console.log(tests[t], result);
        output.innerHTML += "\n" + tests[t] + ": " + result;
    }
})();
```

And results:

```
definedButNotInitialized in window: true
definedAndInitialized in window: false
someObject.firstProp in window: false
someObject.secondProp in window: false
someObject.undefinedProp in window: true
notDefined in window: Exception--ReferenceError: notDefined is not defined
"definedButNotInitialized" in window: false
"definedAndInitialized" in window: true
"someObject.firstProp" in window: false
"someObject.secondProp" in window: false
"someObject.undefinedProp" in window: false
"notDefined" in window: false
typeof definedButNotInitialized == "undefined": true
typeof definedButNotInitialized === typeof undefined: true
definedButNotInitialized === undefined: true
! definedButNotInitialized: true
!! definedButNotInitialized: false
typeof definedAndInitialized == "undefined": false
typeof definedAndInitialized === typeof undefined: false
definedAndInitialized === undefined: false
! definedAndInitialized: false
!! definedAndInitialized: true
typeof someObject.firstProp == "undefined": false
typeof someObject.firstProp === typeof undefined: false
someObject.firstProp === undefined: false
! someObject.firstProp: false
!! someObject.firstProp: true
typeof someObject.secondProp == "undefined": false
typeof someObject.secondProp === typeof undefined: false
someObject.secondProp === undefined: false
! someObject.secondProp: true
!! someObject.secondProp: false
typeof someObject.undefinedProp == "undefined": true
typeof someObject.undefinedProp === typeof undefined: true
someObject.undefinedProp === undefined: true
! someObject.undefinedProp: true
!! someObject.undefinedProp: false
typeof notDefined == "undefined": true
typeof notDefined === typeof undefined: true
notDefined === undefined: Exception--ReferenceError: notDefined is not defined
! notDefined: Exception--ReferenceError: notDefined is not defined
!! notDefined: Exception--ReferenceError: notDefined is not defined
```

Answer (score 21):

If you do

```
if (myvar == undefined )
{ 
    alert('var does not exists or is not initialized');
}
```

it will fail when the variable `myvar` does not exists, because myvar is not defined, so the script is broken and the test has no effect.

Because the window object has a global scope (default object) outside a function, a declaration will be 'attached' to the window object.

For example:

```
var myvar = 'test';
```

The global variable *myvar* is the same as *window.myvar* or *window['myvar']*

To avoid errors to test when a global variable exists, you better use:

```
if(window.myvar == undefined )
{ 
    alert('var does not exists or is not initialized');
}
```

The question if a variable really exists doesn't matter, its value is incorrect. Otherwise, it is silly to initialize variables with undefined, and it is better use the value false to initialize. When you know that all variables that you declare are initialized with false, you can simply check its type or rely on `!window.myvar` to check if it has a proper/valid value. So even when the variable is not defined then `!window.myvar` is the same for `myvar = undefined` or `myvar = false` or `myvar = 0`.

When you expect a specific type, test the type of the variable. To speed up testing a condition you better do:

```
if( !window.myvar || typeof window.myvar != 'string' )
{
    alert('var does not exists or is not type of string');
}
```

When the first and simple condition is true, the interpreter skips the next tests.

It is always better to use the instance/object of the variable to check if it got a valid value. It is more stable and is a better way of programming.

(y)

Answer (score 16):

[ECMAScript 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#10th_Edition_%E2%80%93_ECMAScript_2019) introduced a new feature - **optional chaining** which you can use to use a property of an object only when an object is defined like this:

```
const userPhone = user?.contactDetails?.phone;
```

It will reference to the phone property only when user and contactDetails are defined.

Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: I used to use a lot the function get from lodash, very convenient for accessing this kind of  objects, but the new optional chaining covers up most of the uses of _.get

Comment: This is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 15):

In the article *[Exploring the Abyss of Null and Undefined in JavaScript](http://flippinawesome.org/2013/12/09/exploring-the-abyss-of-null-and-undefined-in-javascript/)*  I read that frameworks like [Underscore.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underscore.js) use this function:

```
function isUndefined(obj){
    return obj === void 0;
}
```

Comment: `void 0` is just a short way of writing `undefined` (since that's what *void* followed by any expression returns), it saves 3 charcters. It could also do `var a; return obj === a;`, but that's one more character. :-)

Comment: `void` is a reserved word, whereas `undefined` is not i.e. while `undefined` is equal to `void 0` by default, you can assign a value to `undefined` e.g. `undefined = 1234`.

Comment: `isUndefined(obj)`: 16 chars.   `obj === void 0`:  14 chars. 'nough said.

Answer (score 15):

Simply anything is not defined in JavaScript, is **undefined**, doesn't matter if it's a property inside an **Object/Array** or as just a simple variable...

JavaScript has `typeof` which make it very easy to detect an undefined variable.

Simply check if `typeof whatever === 'undefined'` and it will return a boolean.

That's how the famous function `isUndefined()` in AngularJs v.1x is written:

```
function isUndefined(value) {return typeof value === 'undefined';}
```

So as you see the function receive a value, if that value is defined, it will return `false`, otherwise for undefined values, return `true`.

So let's have a look what gonna be the results when we passing values, including object properties like below, this is the list of variables we have:

```
var stackoverflow = {};
stackoverflow.javascipt = 'javascript';
var today;
var self = this;
var num = 8;
var list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var y = null;
```

and we check them as below, you can see the results in front of them as a comment:

```
isUndefined(stackoverflow); //false
isUndefined(stackoverflow.javascipt); //false
isUndefined(today); //true
isUndefined(self); //false
isUndefined(num); //false
isUndefined(list); //false
isUndefined(y); //false
isUndefined(stackoverflow.java); //true
isUndefined(stackoverflow.php); //true
isUndefined(stackoverflow && stackoverflow.css); //true
```

As you see we can check anything with using something like this in our code, as mentioned you can simply use `typeof` in your code, but if you are using it over and over, create a function like the angular sample which I share and keep reusing as following DRY code pattern.

Also one more thing, for checking property on an object in a real application which you not sure even the object exists or not, check if the object exists first.

If you check a property on an object and the object doesn't exist, will throw an error and stop the whole application running.

```
isUndefined(x.css);
VM808:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined(…)
```

So simple you can wrap inside an if statement like below:

```
if(typeof x !== 'undefined') {
  //do something
}
```

Which also equal to isDefined in Angular 1.x...

```
function isDefined(value) {return typeof value !== 'undefined';}
```

Also other javascript frameworks like underscore has similar defining check, but I recommend you use `typeof` if you already not using any frameworks.

I also add this section from MDN which has got useful information about typeof, undefined and void(0).

> **Strict equality and undefined** 
>  You can use undefined and the strict equality and inequality operators to determine whether a variable has
>   a value. In the following code, the variable x is not defined, and the
>   if statement evaluates to true.

```
var x;
if (x === undefined) {
   // these statements execute
}
else {
   // these statements do not execute
}
```

> Note: The strict equality operator rather than the standard equality
>   operator must be used here, because x == undefined also checks whether
>   x is null, while strict equality doesn't. null is not equivalent to
>   undefined. See comparison operators for details.

---

> **Typeof operator and undefined** 
>   Alternatively, typeof can be used:

```
var x;
if (typeof x === 'undefined') {
   // these statements execute
}
```

> One reason to use typeof is that it does not throw an error if the
>   variable has not been declared.

```
// x has not been declared before
if (typeof x === 'undefined') { // evaluates to true without errors
   // these statements execute
}

if (x === undefined) { // throws a ReferenceError

}
```

> However, this kind of technique should be avoided. JavaScript is a
>   statically scoped language, so knowing if a variable is declared can
>   be read by seeing whether it is declared in an enclosing context. The
>   only exception is the global scope, but the global scope is bound to
>   the global object, so checking the existence of a variable in the
>   global context can be done by checking the existence of a property on
>   the global object (using the in operator, for instance).

---

> **Void operator and undefined**
>
> The void operator is a third alternative.

```
var x;
if (x === void 0) {
   // these statements execute
}

// y has not been declared before
if (y === void 0) {
   // throws a ReferenceError (in contrast to `typeof`)
}
```

more > [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)

Answer (score 13):

### '*if (window.x) { }*' is error safe

Most likely you want `if (window.x)`. This check is safe even if x hasn't been declared (`var x;`) - browser doesn't throw an error.

### Example: I want to know if my browser supports History API

```
if (window.history) {
    history.call_some_function();
}
```

### How this works:

**window** is an object which holds all global variables as its members, and it is legal to try to access a non-existing member. If **x** hasn't been declared or hasn't been set then `window.x` returns **undefined**. **undefined** leads to **false** when **if()** evaluates it.

Comment: But what if you run in Node? `typeof history != 'undefined'` actually works in both systems.

Answer (score 13):

```
"propertyName" in obj //-> true | false
```

Answer (score 13):

Reading through this, I'm amazed I didn't see this. I have found multiple algorithms that would work for this.

## Never Defined

If the value of an object was never defined, this will prevent from returning `true` if it is defined as `null` or `undefined`. This is helpful if you want true to be returned for values set as `undefined`

```
if(obj.prop === void 0) console.log("The value has never been defined");
```

## Defined as undefined Or never Defined

If you want it to result as `true` for values defined with the value of `undefined`, or never defined, you can simply use `=== undefined`

```
if(obj.prop === undefined) console.log("The value is defined as undefined, or never defined");
```

## Defined as a falsy value, undefined,null, or never defined.

Commonly, people have asked me for an algorithm to figure out if a value is either falsy, `undefined`, or `null`. The following works.

```
if(obj.prop == false || obj.prop === null || obj.prop === undefined) {
    console.log("The value is falsy, null, or undefined");
}
```

Comment: I think you can replace the last example with `if (!obj.prop)`

Comment: @StijndeWitt, you can, I was pretty inexperienced when I wrote this, and my English seems to have been equally bad, nevertheless, there isn't anything *incorrect* in the answer

Comment: `var obj = {foo: undefined}; obj.foo === void 0` -> `true`. How is that "never defined as `undefined`"? This is wrong.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts You're right. When I wrote this answer in February 2015 (before ES6) the first option I outlined did indeed work, but it is now outdated.

Answer (score 12):

The solution is incorrect. In JavaScript,

```
null == undefined
```

will return true, because they both are "casted" to a boolean and are false. The correct way would be to check

```
if (something === undefined)
```

which is the identity operator...

Comment: To be clear, `===` is type equality + (primitive equality | object identity), where primitives include strings. I think most people consider `'abab'.slice(0,2) === 'abab'.slice(2)` unintuitive if one considers `===` as the identity operator.

Comment: Wrong.  This throws an error if the variable has not been created.  Should not be voted up.  Use typeof instead.

Comment: What solution? Can you link directly to it?

Answer (score 10):

You can get an array all undefined with path using the following code.

```
 function getAllUndefined(object) {

        function convertPath(arr, key) {
            var path = "";
            for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {

                path += arr[i] + "->";
            }
            path += key;
            return path;
        }


        var stack = [];
        var saveUndefined= [];
        function getUndefiend(obj, key) {

            var t = typeof obj;
            switch (t) {
                case "object":
                    if (t === null) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "string":
                case "number":
                case "boolean":
                case "null":
                    return false;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
            stack.push(key);
            for (k in obj) {
                if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                    v = getUndefiend(obj[k], k);
                    if (v) {
                        saveUndefined.push(convertPath(stack, k));
                    }
                }
            }
            stack.pop();

        }

        getUndefiend({
            "": object
        }, "");
        return saveUndefined;
    }
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anoop26667/9XbEK/) link

Comment: While it won't affect the validity of your code, you've got a typo: `getUndefiend` should be `getUndefined`.

Answer (score 10):

Compare with `void 0`, for terseness.

```
if (foo !== void 0)
```

It's not as verbose as `if (typeof foo !== 'undefined')`

Comment: But it will throw a ReferenceError if `foo` is undeclared.

Comment: @daniel1426: So if there's an error in your code, you want to hide it instead of fixing it? Not a great approach, IMO.

Comment: This is not used to hide errors. It's the common way to detect the properties of the environment to define polyfills. For instance:

if( typeof Promise === 'undefined' ){ /* define Promise */ }

Answer (score 9):

There is a nice and elegant way to assign a defined property to a new variable if it is defined or assign a default value to it as a fallback if it’s undefined.

```
var a = obj.prop || defaultValue;
```

It’s suitable if you have a function, which receives an additional configuration property:

```
var yourFunction = function(config){

   this.config = config || {};
   this.yourConfigValue = config.yourConfigValue || 1;
   console.log(this.yourConfigValue);
}
```

Now executing

```
yourFunction({yourConfigValue:2});
//=> 2

yourFunction();
//=> 1

yourFunction({otherProperty:5});
//=> 1
```

Comment: Using || (OR) will use type coertion for "undefined" and "null" values to false, and every other values to "true". ------- If property checked (in example "obj.prop" and "config") is undefined or null it will be assigned 'default value'. In any other the value will not be changed.  -------- This soultion doesn't check if the object HAS property defined. ------------------------------------------------ To check if object has a property you can use: 

`let objAndPropCheck = (obj || { }).prop || 0;`

Answer (score 8):

Here is my situation:

I am using the result of a REST call. The result should be parsed from JSON to a JavaScript object.

There is one error I need to defend. If the arguments to the REST call were incorrect as far as the user specifying the arguments wrong, the REST call comes back basically empty.

While using this post to help me defend against this, I tried this:

```
if( typeof restResult.data[0] === "undefined" ) { throw  "Some error"; }
```

For my situation, if restResult.data[0] === "object", then I can safely start inspecting the rest of the members. If undefined then throw the error as above.

What I am saying is that for my situation, all the previous suggestions in this post did not work. I'm not saying I'm right and everyone is wrong. I am not a JavaScript master at all, but hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: Your `typeof` guard doesn't actually guard against anything that a direct comparison couldn't handle. If `restResult` is undefined or undeclared, it'll still throw.

Comment: In your case you could more simply check if the array is empty: `if(!restResult.data.length) { throw "Some error"; }`

Answer (score 7):

All the answers are incomplete. This is the right way of knowing that there is a property 'defined as undefined':

```
var hasUndefinedProperty = function hasUndefinedProperty(obj, prop){
  return ((prop in obj) && (typeof obj[prop] == 'undefined'));
};
```

Example:

```
var a = { b : 1, e : null };
a.c = a.d;

hasUndefinedProperty(a, 'b'); // false: b is defined as 1
hasUndefinedProperty(a, 'c'); // true: c is defined as undefined
hasUndefinedProperty(a, 'd'); // false: d is undefined
hasUndefinedProperty(a, 'e'); // false: e is defined as null

// And now...
delete a.c ;
hasUndefinedProperty(a, 'c'); // false: c is undefined
```

Too bad that this been the right answer and is buried in wrong answers >_<

So, for anyone who pass by, I will give you undefined's for free!!

```
var undefined ; undefined ; // undefined
({}).a ;                    // undefined
[].a ;                      // undefined
''.a ;                      // undefined
(function(){}()) ;          // undefined
void(0) ;                   // undefined
eval() ;                    // undefined
1..a ;                      // undefined
/a/.a ;                     // undefined
(true).a ;                  // undefined
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a very easy and simple way.

You can use **optional chaining**:

```
x = {prop:{name:"sajad"}}

console.log(x.prop?.name) // Output is: "sajad"
console.log(x.prop?.lastName) // Output is: undefined
```

or

```
if(x.prop?.lastName) // The result of this 'if' statement is false and is not throwing an error
```

You can use optional chaining even for functions or arrays.

As of mid-2020 this is not universally implemented. Check the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 6):

Going through the comments, for those who want to check both is it undefined or its value is null:

```
//Just in JavaScript
var s; // Undefined
if (typeof s == "undefined" || s === null){
    alert('either it is undefined or value is null')
}
```

If you are using jQuery Library then `jQuery.isEmptyObject()` will suffice for both cases,

```
var s; // Undefined
jQuery.isEmptyObject(s); // Will return true;

s = null; // Defined as null
jQuery.isEmptyObject(s); // Will return true;

//Usage
if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(s)) {
    alert('Either variable:s is undefined or its value is null');
} else {
     alert('variable:s has value ' + s);
}

s = 'something'; // Defined with some value
jQuery.isEmptyObject(s); // Will return false;
```

Comment: jQuery will also take care of any cross-browser compatibility issues with the different JavaScript APIs.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Angular:

```
angular.isUndefined(obj)
angular.isUndefined(obj.prop)
```

Underscore.js:

```
_.isUndefined(obj) 
_.isUndefined(obj.prop)
```

Comment: How do I add `1` to variable `x`? Do I need Underscore or jQuery?  (amazing that people will use libraries for even the most elementary operations such as a `typeof` check)

Answer (score 6):

I provide three ways here for those who expect weird answers:

```js
function isUndefined1(val) {
    try {
        val.a;
    } catch (e) {
        return /undefined/.test(e.message);
    }
    return false;
}

function isUndefined2(val) {
    return !val && val+'' === 'undefined';
}

function isUndefined3(val) {
    const defaultVal = {};
    return ((input = defaultVal) => input === defaultVal)(val);
}

function test(func){
    console.group(`test start :`+func.name);
    console.log(func(undefined));
    console.log(func(null));
    console.log(func(1));
    console.log(func("1"));
    console.log(func(0));
    console.log(func({}));
    console.log(func(function () { }));
    console.groupEnd();
}
test(isUndefined1);
test(isUndefined2);
test(isUndefined3);
```

#### isUndefined1:

Try to get a property of the input value, and check the error message if it exists. If the input value is undefined, the error message would be *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of undefined*.

#### isUndefined2:

Convert the input value to a string to compare with `"undefined"` and ensure it's a negative value.

#### isUndefined3:

In JavaScript, an optional parameter works when the input value is exactly `undefined`.

Answer (score 5):

I use `if (this.variable)` to test if it is defined. A simple `if (variable)`, [recommended in a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property/12589152#12589152), fails for me.

It turns out that it works only when a variable is a field of some object, `obj.someField` to check if it is defined in the dictionary. But we can use `this` or `window` as the dictionary object since any variable is a field in the current window, as I understand it. Therefore here is a test:

```js
if (this.abc) 
    alert("defined"); 
else 
    alert("undefined");

abc = "abc";
if (this.abc) 
    alert("defined"); 
else 
    alert("undefined");
```

It first detects that variable `abc` is undefined and it is defined after initialization.

Answer (score 4):

```
function isUnset(inp) {
  return (typeof inp === 'undefined')
}
```

Returns false if variable is set, and true if is undefined.

Then use:

```
if (isUnset(var)) {
  // initialize variable here
}
```

Comment: No. Don't do this. It only takes a [very simple test](https://jsfiddle.net/wcj6xpa7/1/) to prove that you cannot meaningfully wrap a `typeof` test in a function. Amazing that 4 people upvoted this. -1.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to show you something I'm using in order to protect the `undefined` variable:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'undefined', {});
```

This forbids anyone to change the `window.undefined` value therefore destroying the code based on that variable. If using `"use strict"`, anything trying to change its value will end in error, otherwise it would be silently ignored.

Answer (score 4):

From lodash.js.

```
var undefined;
function isUndefined(value) {
  return value === undefined;
}
```

It creates a *local* variable named `undefined` which is initialized with the default value -- the real `undefined`, then compares `value` with the variable `undefined`.

---

Update 9/9/2019

I found Lodash updated its implementation. See [my issue](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/4041) and [the code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4ea8c2ec249be046a0f4ae32539d652194caf74f/isUndefined.js#L17).

To be bullet-proof, simply use:

```
function isUndefined(value) {
  return value === void 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a Proxy. It will work with nested calls, but it will require one extra check:

```
function resolveUnknownProps(obj, resolveKey) {
  const handler = {
    get(target, key) {
      if (
        target[key] !== null &&
        typeof target[key] === 'object'
      ) {
        return resolveUnknownProps(target[key], resolveKey);
      } else if (!target[key]) {
        return resolveUnknownProps({ [resolveKey]: true }, resolveKey);
      }

      return target[key];
    },
  };

  return new Proxy(obj, handler);
}

const user = {}

console.log(resolveUnknownProps(user, 'isUndefined').personalInfo.name.something.else); // { isUndefined: true }
```

So you will use it like:

```
const { isUndefined } = resolveUnknownProps(user, 'isUndefined').personalInfo.name.something.else;
if (!isUndefined) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In recent JavaScript release there is new chaining operator introduced, which is most probably best way to check if property exists else it will give you undefined

see example below

```
  const adventurer = {
  name: 'Alice',
  cat: {
    name: 'Dinah'
  }
};

const dogName = adventurer.dog?.name;
console.log(dogName);
// expected output: undefined

console.log(adventurer.someNonExistentMethod?.());
// expected output: undefined
```

We can replace this old syntax

```
if (response && response.data && response.data.someData && response.data.someData.someMoreData) {}
```

with this neater syntax

```
if( response?.data?.someData?.someMoreData) {}
```

This syntax is not supported in IE, Opera, safari & samsund android

for more detail you can check this URL

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 2):

Also, the same things can be written shorter:

```
if (!variable){
    // Do it if the variable is undefined
}
```

or

```
if (variable){
    // Do it if the variable is defined
}
```

Comment: Your first case can be triggered by defined variable. For example if variable = 0, !variable will trigger. So your answer is quite wrong.

Comment: I think just wrong wording, I think he meant "do it if variable is undefined or another falsy value" which is often the logic that people are looking for.

Comment: @Ynot - `!variable` would be true is `variable` is undefined, or *is defined* and happens to be equal to **0**, **false**, *etc*. I don't see how that's either an answer to OP's question, or remotely useful.

Comment: I did not upvote this because I didn't think it was the best answer.  I thought Stranded Kid brought up a good point but that he mischaracterized the solution.  Just because you can imagine a use case where something is wrong doesn't mean there exists no use case where it is right.  It is directly related to the OP's question in that, if you understand the implications then this can be used without issue to check if a property is undefined (|| false).  e.g. checking a flag `if (myobject.isFeatureEnabled) {`

Answer (score 2):

Use:

**To check if property is undefined:**

```
if (typeof something === "undefined") {
    alert("undefined");
}
```

**To check if property is not undefined:**

```
if (typeof something !== "undefined") {
    alert("not undefined");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're going to also want to check for it being *either* `undefined` or `null`. If so, I suggest:

`myVar == null`

This is one of the only times a **double equals** is very helpful as it will evaluate to `true` when `myVar` is `undefined` or `null`, but it will evaluate to `false` when it is other falsey values such as `0`, `false`, `''`, and `NaN`.

This the actual [the source code](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L11987) for Lodash's [`isNil`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isNil) method.

Comment: Surprised this hasn't gotten more upvotes or comments. What do people think about this?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to check if a key exists is to use `in`:

```
if (key in obj) {
  // Do something
} else {
  // Create key
}

const obj = {
  0: 'abc',
  1: 'def'
}

const hasZero = 0 in obj

console.log(hasZero) // true
```

Comment: As the OP is specifically asking about if a property in an object is defined, this is now the most direct and straightforward answer for anybody using modern JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised I haven't seen this suggestion yet, but it gets even more specificity than testing with `typeof`. Use [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) if you need to know whether an object property was initialized with `undefined` or if it was never initialized:

```
// to test someObject.someProperty
var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(someObject, 'someProperty');

if (typeof descriptor === 'undefined') {
  // was never initialized
} else if (typeof descriptor.value === 'undefined') {
  if (descriptor.get || descriptor.set) {
    // is an accessor property, defined via getter and setter
  } else {
    // is initialized with `undefined`
  }
} else {
  // is initialized with some other value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Introduced in **ECMAScript 6**, we can now deal with `undefined` in a new way using Proxies. It can be used to set a default value to any properties which doesn't exist so that we don't have to check each time whether it actually exists.

```
var handler = {
  get: function(target, name) {
    return name in target ? target[name] : 'N/A';
  }
};

var p = new Proxy({}, handler);
p.name = 'Kevin';
console.log('Name: ' +p.name, ', Age: '+p.age, ', Gender: '+p.gender)
```

Will output the below text without getting any undefined.

```
Name: Kevin , Age: N/A , Gender: N/A
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the only explicit form of determining if the existing property-name has an explicit and intended value of `undefined`; which is, nonetheless, a JavaScript type.

```
"propertyName" in containerObject && ""+containerObject["propertyName"] == "undefined";
>> true \ false
```

This expression will only return `true` if the property name of the given context exists (truly) and only if its intended value is explicitly `undefined`.

There will be no false positives like with empty or blank strings zeros nulls or empty arrays and alike. This does exactly that. Checks i.e., makes sure the property name exists (otherwise it would be a false positive), than it explicitly checks if its value is `undefined` e.g. of an undefined JavaScript type in it's string representation form (literally "undefined") therefore `==` instead of `===` because no further conversion is possible. And this expression will only return true if both, that is all conditions are met. E.g. if the property-name doesn't exist, - it will return false. Which is the only correct return since nonexistent properties can't have values, not even an undefined one.

Example:

```
containerObject = { propertyName: void "anything" }
>> Object { propertyName: undefined }

// Now the testing

"propertyName" in containerObject && ""+containerObject["propertyName"] == "undefined";
>> true

/* Which makes sure that nonexistent property will not return a false positive
 * unless it is previously defined  */

"foo" in containerObject && ""+containerObject["foo"] == "undefined";
>> false
```

Comment: And what if the property has the *string* value `"undefined"`? ...as in `containerObject = { propertyName: "undefined" }`

Comment: lol, ok then... you'll get the exact false positive that you claim your code prevents. https://jsfiddle.net/pfwx5j51/

Comment: ...also, with your code `==` and `===` will behave identically because you're always comparing matching types. So that distinction is immaterial.

Comment: @rockstar Exactly, - you don't need a static comparison operator on arguments of the same type. That'd be an overkill.
Furthermore if the value of a property is a string of undefined, or a type of undefined, doesn't change a thing. Because they both have the same meaning and equal yield. You can spare yourself a few bits in assigning "undefined" as a property value. That's an overkill Because you will be able to retrieve a string of undefined without having to assign it. I agree - technically you may consider it a 'false positive' - but practically & empirically, it is not. Thanks anyway.

Comment: On arguments of the same type, the `===`  and `==` do the exact same work. When the types don't match the `==` does *more* work, so calling `===` "overkill" makes little sense, as it always provides an equal or simpler algorithm.

Comment: The  `undefined` and `"undefined"` have the same meaning only in your test, which is what makes it a false positive, since your test's objective is to find exactly that kind of distinction. So it's a clear fail, and would be needlessly complex anyway since `("prop" in obj) && obj.prop === undefined` is simpler and is actually correct. Yep, you're welcome.

Comment: @rockstar you false positive case is never the case. And when it is - it is deliberate and therefore equal, but if you feel that strong about it  feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say it's deliberate and therefore equal. One can have the string value `"undefined"` for many different reasons, so unless there's a highly unusual situation, the string `"undefined"` should be just as distinct from the value `undefined` as the string `"foobar"` is.

Comment: That's the point, I'm not being able to to see any other reason of assigning an undefined value as a string, except to use this value a a word meaning undefined in some readable text and therefore it's an overkill because there's no need to actually write it in order to be able to retrieve it. p.s === is an overkill in JS when dealing with same type args because JS is dynamic by birth, not by extension. Strictness needs to be forced on it. Anyway, you are most welcome to correct my mistake. That way it will take your signature.

Comment: It's a pretty common misconception that the `===` has to do more work because of JS's dynamic nature, but it actually has to do less, because when the types don't match, it's able to [return `false` immediately](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) instead of entering into a recursive coercion algorithm. It's the type coercion that needs to be forced, which is what `==` does when the types don't match. When they do match, `==` and `===` [use identical algorithms](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison).

Comment: ...As to `undefined`, it's probably pretty rare to have that as an explicit value anyway, but if one is checking for it, then they probably use it for a reason (though `null` is arguably better). In that case, I think they'd want to ensure a distinction. Anyway, just pointing out that it can conflict with the intent in those cases.

Comment: Don't ever use null for what it's not.

Comment: Oh, don't worry, I won't. That's why I say it's arguably better than `undefined` to represent a *defined* property that doesn't have a useful value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JavaScript object function like this:

```
var ojb ={
    age: 12
}

if(ojb.hasOwnProperty('name')){
    console.log('property exists and is not undefined');
}
```

The above method returns `true` if it got that property or the property is not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few little helpers in the [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) library:

[isUndefined](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#isUndefined) - to check if *value* is `undefined`.

```
_.isUndefined(undefined) // => true
_.isUndefined(null) // => false
```

[has](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#has) - to check if object contains a property

```
const object = { 'a': { 'b': 2 } }

_.has(object, 'a.b') // => true
_.has(object, 'a.c') // => false
```

Answer (score 0):

## Review

A lot of the given answers give a wrong result because they do not distinguish between the case when an object property does not exist and the case when a property has value `undefined`. Here is **proof** for most popular solutions:

```js
let obj = {
  a: 666,
  u: undefined // The 'u' property has value 'undefined'
               // The 'x' property does not exist
}

console.log('>>> good results:');
console.log('A', "u" in obj, "x" in obj);
console.log('B', obj.hasOwnProperty("u"),      obj.hasOwnProperty("x"));

console.log('\n>>> bad results:');
console.log('C', obj.u === undefined,          obj.x === undefined);
console.log('D', obj.u == undefined,           obj.x == undefined);
console.log('E', obj["u"] === undefined,       obj["x"] === undefined);
console.log('F', obj["u"] == undefined,        obj["x"] == undefined);
console.log('G', !obj.u,                      !obj.x);
console.log('H', typeof obj.u === 'undefined', typeof obj.x === 'undefined');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Version for the use of dynamic variables**
Did you know?

```js
var boo ='lala';

function check(){
  if(this['foo']){
        console.log('foo is here');}
  else{
        console.log('have no foo');
      }

  if(this['boo']){
        console.log('boo is here');}
  else{
        console.log('have no boo');
      }
}

check();
```

Answer (score 0):

handle undefined

```
function isUndefined(variable,defaultvalue=''){

    if (variable == undefined ) return defaultvalue;
    
    return variable;

}
```

```js
var obj={
und:undefined,
notundefined:'hi i am not undefined'
}


function isUndefined(variable,defaultvalue=''){

    if (variable == undefined )
    { 
        return defaultvalue;
    }
    return variable

}

console.log(isUndefined(obj.und,'i am print'))
console.log(isUndefined(obj.notundefined,'i am print'))
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this article [7 Tips to Handle undefined in JavaScript](https://dmitripavlutin.com/7-tips-to-handle-undefined-in-javascript/)

which is showing really interesting things about `undefined`
like:

The existence of undefined is a consequence of JavaScript’s permissive nature that allows the usage of:

- uninitialized variables
- non-existing object properties or methods
- out of bounds indexes to access array elements
- the invocation result of a function that returns nothing

Comment: Yes, but how does it answer the question?

Comment: please follow article.

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, there are **truthy** and **falsy** expressions. If you want to check if the property is undefined or not, there is a straight way of using an **if** condition as given,

1. Using **truthy/falsy** concept.

```js
if(!ob.someProp){
    console.log('someProp is falsy')
}
```

However, there are several more approaches to check the object has property or not, but it seems long to me. Here are those.

2. Using **`=== undefined`** check in **`if`** condition

```js
if(ob.someProp === undefined){
    console.log('someProp is undefined')
}
```

3. Using **`typeof`**

**`typeof`** acts as a combined check for the value undefined and for whether a variable exists.

```js
if(typeof ob.someProp === 'undefined'){
    console.log('someProp is undefined')
}
```

4. Using **`hasOwnProperty`** method

The JavaScript object has built in the `hasOwnProperty` function in the object prototype.

```js
if(!ob.hasOwnProperty('someProp')){
    console.log('someProp is undefined')
}
```

Not going in deep, but the 1<sup>st</sup> way looks shortened and good to me. Here are the details on [truthy/falsy](https://howtodoinjava.com/typescript/truthy-and-falsy/) values in JavaScript and `undefined` is the falsy value listed in there. So the `if` condition behaves normally without any glitch. Apart from the `undefined`, values `NaN`, `false` (Obviously), `''` (empty string) and number `0` are also the falsy values.

> **Warning**: *Make sure the property value does not contain any falsy value, otherwise the `if` condition will return false. For such a case, you can use the `hasOwnProperty` method*

Comment: ... do you also check the code examples you are posting ?... e.g ... `if (typeof ob.someProp === undefined) { ...`

Comment: ... you also can not nonchalantly "fix/patch" your provided examples that are answering how to check for an undefined property by exclaiming a **Warning** afterwards ... actually `if (!ob.someProp) { console.log('someProp is undefined'); }` from the beginning has to be implemented as `if (!ob.someProp) { console.log('someProp is falsy'); }`

Comment: @PeterSeliger Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: I also was pointing to your No.3 / typeof example ... it is still implemented wrong ... it should be ... `if (typeof ob.someProp === 'undefined') {` ... your code does not compare against a string value but against the undefined value. Thats why the question about if you do actually test before you post.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Thanks again for noticing, well' I wrote this directly into the post so it's susceptible to error. I would have fiddle before posting. Correcting is done

Answer (score -2):

`Object.hasOwnProperty(o, 'propertyname');`

This doesn't look up through the prototype chain, however.

Comment: `Object.hasOwnProperty` won't work as expected; it checks if the `Object` object has a property with the name contained in `o`. You probably mean `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, 'propertyname')`.

Answer (score -21):

```
if (somevariable == undefined) {
  alert('the variable is not defined!');
}
```

You can also make it into a function, as shown [here](http://verens.com/archives/2005/07/25/isset-for-javascript/):

```
function isset(varname){
  return(typeof(window[varname]) != 'undefined');
}
```

Comment: First, when somevariable equals undefined, it doesn't mean the variable is undefined - it's just the value that is undefined. When the variable is undefined, then this code will throw an error. Second, this isset function will only work for global variables.

Comment: what about local variables?  
strange trick with window[variable]